# cakephp email error with SMTP server did not accept the password. Less secure apps is enabled

Tags: php, cakephp, email-client

I am using cakephp4 and the email I set up on local works but the same code on my server https using email gives and error with SMTP server did not accept the password. Less secure apps is enabled.  Since the code is identical I have no idea what to do. This works on my local as I can send emails fine  but not on the server in sending an email?

```
 'gmail3' => [
        
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username'=>'xx@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'xx',
        'client' => null,
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'context' => [
          'ssl' => [
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
             'allow_self_signed' => true
                 ]
             ]

 //sending an email
 $Email = new Mailer('default');
                     
                    $Email->getTransport('gmail3'); 
                 
                    $Email->setFrom([$this->from => 'My Email'])
                      ->setTo($to)
                      ->setSubject($subject)
                      ->deliver($message);
```

The domain that it doesnt work on is https://test.choiceeducationgroup.com

Comment: I'm not using Gmail, so I can't really help, but Isn't the less secure apps feature going to be disabled in like 3 days? Maybe you should try using an app password, there's a chance that you'll also avoid whatever problem you're running into with using the regular password that way.

Comment: i changed to app password but same issue

Answer (score 0):

If I change to app password in gmail then it does work.